# Increment an alphanumeric string property using ef core

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

**Overview of the project**

I have a .net core 6 web api project which uses postgresql as the database and ef core 6 as the ORM to connect to the database. The project is setup to use code first approach.

**Problem Statement**

One of the entities in the project "Transaction" has a alpha numeric string property by the name "ReferenceCode" (not a primary key). The reference code has the format of "TR00001", "TR00002" where in the value has to increase for every transaction object creation.

```cs
public class Transaction : AuditableEntity<Guid>
{
    public Guid AccountId { get; private set; }
    public string? ReferenceCode { get; private set; } //Property of concern
    public TransactionType TransactionType { get; private set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; private set; }
    public string? UserComments { get; private set; }
    public string? TransactionComments { get; private set; }
    public DateTime MadeOn { get; private set; }
}
```

Currently I have employed the approach of incrementing the value manually inside of the code as shown inline.

```cs
var currentCount = this.applicationDbContext.Transactions.Count(); //created entries will not be deleted from database
var referenceCode = "TR" + string.Format("{0:0000000000}", currentCount + 1);
var transactionInToAccount = new Transaction(Guid.NewGuid(), request.ToAccountId, referenceCode, Domain.Transaction.TransactionType.Deposit, request.Amount, request.UserComments, request.TransactionComments, request.MadeOn, this.currentUser.GetUserId());
```

This code is causing problems by creating same reference code for different transaction objects when we have concurrent requests for transaction creation. So is there a way to solve this problem in code first approach?

Comment: Query for the maximum code by sorting descending on code and taking the first one. Remove the "TR" from the code. Use int.Parse to convert to code to a valid number. Increase the number. Create the new code using the format.

Comment: The safest (and most hassle-free) way is to add an identity column to the `Transaction` table, named something like "SequenceNumber" and a computed column that adds the prefix + format. (You have accepts "holes" in the number sequence though).

Comment: Computed columns sounds promising. Let me check that out.